# Array is always picking the first value instead of specific value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```
refreshFileList = function() {
  $("#filedetails tr").remove();
  for (i = 0, j = fileDetails.length; i < j; ++i) {
    $("#filedetails").append("<tr data-filesize='" + fileDetails[i].SIZE + "'  data-filename='" + fileDetails[i].KEY + "'><td><strong>" + fileDetails[i].FILENAME + "</strong></td><td class='nodesize'>" + fileDetails[i].SIZE + " MB</td><td>" + fileDetails[i].EXT + "</td>" + fileDetails[i].TAG + "</tr>");
  }
},

fileDelete = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var parentRow = jQuery(this).closest('tr')
    , fileName = fileDetails[i].KEY
    , fileSize = fileDetails[i].SIZE;
    ajaxFileDelete(fileName, parentRow, fileSize);
},
```

Into the fileDelete function I don't want to use data-filename and data-filesize but when I am going to use fileName = fileDetails[i].KEY or fileSize = fileDetails[i].SIZE its always deleting the first value of the array instead of specific value but with data-attributes it working as expected.

Comment: Is this the code that works or the one that doesn't work? If you want to know why your code doesn't work, you need to show the non-working version, not some other code that doesn't have the problem.

Comment: I have updated I am not sure how to get the values from that specific row instead of getting data from first element of array

Comment: How do you think the code is going to know what `i` is in `fileDelete`?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `data-filename` and `data-filesize`?

Comment: I have list where 3 files r added.. when I am clicking on delete button its always removing the 1st record doesn't matter where do i click. I wanted to remove only that specific clicked row record

Comment: Since I am already getting the values in fileDetails[i], i want to remove extra code/assignation

Comment: BTW, you should declare `i` and `j` as local variables in `refreshFileList`.

Comment: Then you need some way to pass the value of `i` to the function. You could put `data-index='" + i + "'` in the TR, then use `var i = parentRow.data("index")`

Comment: What was the point of adding `data-filename` and `data-filesize` if you're not going to use them?

Comment: i want to get rid of the them n use that specific row filename n filesize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `i` to the `<tr>` as a `data` attribute.

```
refreshFileList = function() {
  $("#filedetails tr").remove();
  for (var i = 0, j = fileDetails.length; i < j; ++i) {
    $("#filedetails").append("<tr data-index='" + i + "'><td><strong>" + fileDetails[i].FILENAME + "</strong></td><td class='nodesize'>" + fileDetails[i].SIZE + " MB</td><td>" + fileDetails[i].EXT + "</td>" + fileDetails[i].TAG + "</tr>");
  }
},

fileDelete = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var parentRow = jQuery(this).closest('tr')
    , i = parentRow.data('index')
    , fileName = fileDetails[i].KEY
    , fileSize = fileDetails[i].SIZE;
    ajaxFileDelete(fileName, parentRow, fileSize);
},
```

Comment: I am getting an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'KEY' of undefined"

Comment: Is `parentRow` getting the `<tr>` with `data-index` in it?

Comment: Then the problem is with how you're attaching `fileDelete` as an event listener on the element, because it's not setting `this` correctly. Add that to your question.